# how to know if all items are selected in checkedlistbox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Checkbox named 'select all' for checkedlistbox. when unCheck any item in checkedlistbox it unCheck 'select all' checkebox, below code does this job.

but when all items are checked in checkedlistbox it should check 'select all'.

```
for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++) {
    if (!checkedListBox1.GetItemChecked(i))
        checkBox1.Checked = false;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try something like this

```
if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count == checkedListBox1.Items.Count)
{
    //your code goes here  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if (checkedListBox1.CheckedItems.Count == checkedListBox1.Items.Count)
{
    //your code goes here  
}
```